# android - service stops when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, service

when I open the activity of my project I call the `startService(Intent intent)` method to start a new Service. 
When the activity is destroyed the service shouldn't be killed (because I didn't use the `bindService()` method), but the fact is that when I close my activity the service is killed and after a second the system creates a new Service (I verified that, the system calls again the `onCreate()` method of my service). What do I have to do to keep only one service ? Thank you

Comment: What *specifically* does "close my activity" mean?

Comment: I mean I hold the home button and then kill my activity from the list of app open

Comment: Which solution you finally tried ?? Also have you tried @Miguel first solution which was using `android:process=":somenamehere"` does that work for you or not ??

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45520099/1389987

Answer (score 24):

To have a service running independently of your application's main process and to be sure that Android does not kill it while it's doing something, there are two things you should do/try.

1. Run your service in a separate process. You can achieve this by adding the following attribute to your service declaration in the manifest:

   `android:process=":somenamehere"`
2. When your service is running and you do not want it to be killed by the OS, you have to use the `startForeground(int id, Notification notification)` method. When the service finishes whatever is doing and can be killed by the OS, call `stopForeground(boolean removeNotification)`. "startForeground" requires a notification as argument because every foreground service must display a notification so the user realizes about it

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, first point helped me. In my eyes, this is not well explained [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), when they talk about this `android:process`attribute. It's difficult to infer that an activity.finish() will destroy your service if you don't have this attribute correctly set

Answer (score 6):

> I mean I hold the home button and then kill my activity from the list of app open

That does not "close" an activity. That terminates your process. The user is welcome to terminate your process whenever the user wants, whether via this means or through third-party task manager apps. There is nothing you can do about this -- you cannot stop the user from terminating your process. Since your process will stop for other reasons as well (e.g., sheer old age), you have plenty of reasons to handle this case.

Comment: But if the user terminates the process I can't have a service running background? What I need is a service which is completely disconnected from my activity. I need something like a gps tracker, if the user terminates the activity I need the service to run until the user decides to stop it inside the activity.

Comment: @rickyalbert: Your process can be terminated at any time, for any reason, by the user or on Android's own accord. This is why Android offers sticky services, where your service may be restarted at a later point after the process was terminated. This is the behavior that you are seeing. You need to adapt your application logic to work with this. Just because *you* want the user to stop your service through your UI does not matter to the user.

Comment: I see there are applications like MyTracks by Google that track your gps location while doing sports, and if you terminate the process the app kepps tracking your position (there is a notification which reminds it to you), and you can stop the service only if you return on the activity an stop it

Comment: @rickyalbert: "the app kepps tracking your position (there is a notification which reminds it to you)" -- they are using `startForeground()`. "and you can stop the service only if you return on the activity an stop it" -- there are many ways for a user to stop a foreground service, most of which do not involve "return on the activity an stop it".

Comment: CommonsWare is right, *start_sticky* could probably restart the service if the service is terminated accidentally for example by misbehaviour or no more resource to claim, so closing activity on purpose is terminating the system (service will be terminated). I tested it many times on Gingerbread Kitkat, and lollipop , same behaviour

Comment: @CommonsWare How about something like Telegram, it doesn't have any notification, so the service is not a foreground service, but when user terminate it with pushing home button the service still running. do u have any idea?

Comment: @Saman: Pushing the HOME button does not "terminate" anything in Android. It is equivalent to minimizing a window in a desktop OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Please refer to CommonsWare's answer

Old answer: You should override `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method and return `START_STICKY` value as the mode of your service.

this will keeps your service working when the activity is destroyed or even when you exit your app unless you call `stopService(Intent)` explicitly

Comment: I tried to do as you said but I got the same problem, the service is finished and then restarted after a second

Comment: I resolved my problem adding 'startForeground()' in the onCreate() method of my service, thank you I'll vive a look

Comment: @Payam Why do you think START_STICKY is not the solution anymore ??